# PDF/X-1a:2001 file doesn't print PSD's/TIF's with alpha channel

Tags: pdf, printing, adobe-photoshop, transparency, adobe-indesign

I'm outputting a print ready PDF using InDesign's PDF/X-1a:2001 preset. Photoshop images & TIF's with transparency that are placed on coloured boxes aren't printing. It's as if someone has perfectly cut out the images from the document. In Acrobat, the files appear fine, yet when I just imported the pdf into Photoshop it too was cutting out the images.

It seems as if it's an issue with photoshop transparency. The three images that did display correctly are tif's using clipping masks with white backgrounds. The top image is a transparent tif, and the bottom is a transparent psd.

Can anyone offer any suggestions as to what could be causing this issue?

**Example of print proof and Photoshop import**

[image]

**Correct file as viewed in InDesign and Acrobat**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this may have been an issue with spot colours. In the PDF options I went to Ink Manager and selected the Convert (Force?) all spots to process. This corrected the problem in Photoshop and in the final print